# Docker memory storage

Tags: docker, scalability

Docker daemon allows, according to documentatio, using memory storage driver for its images.
Has anybody any daily business experiences with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/docker-memory-storage), memory storage is intended for testing purposes only and should never be used in production.  The only practical purpose I can think of for this might be state testing, such as with Serverspec or Inspec, to validate configurations.  Using memory storage for this purpose *might* be a little faster and use less disk storage.  I'm not sure those benefits are worth the effort to implement.